# How to understand the case expression?

Tags: haskell, case-expression

This example is very intuitive. There are 3 cases for xs, which are empty list, list with only 1 element and list with more than 1 element.

```
describeList :: [a] -> String  
describeList xs = "The list is " ++ case xs of [] -> "empty."  
                                               [x] -> "a singleton list."   
                                               xs -> "a longer list."
```

But I get lost in the following code

```
newtype State s a = StateOf{deState :: s -> (s, a)}

postInc :: State Int Int
postInc = StateOf (\i -> (i+1, i))

instance Monad (State s) where
    return a = pure a
    StateOf t >>= k = StateOf (\i0 -> case t i0 of
                                  (i1, a) -> deState (k a) i1)
```

I totally don't know what `i1` and `a` represent.

Comment: It's pattern matching on a tuple where `i1` is the first element (of type `s`) and `a` is the second element (of type `a`).

Comment: It's a more efficient version of `let i1 = fst (t i0) ; a = snd (t i0) in deState (k a) i1`, unpacking the pair resulting from the application `t i0` into a value `a` and a new state `i1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell uses two data structures for managing several values: lists and tuples. Tuples have fixed length and don't need to be of the same type:

```
(1, "2") :: (Int, String)
```

You also can pattern match the values of the tuple. Just for an example:

```
nonBlank :: (Int, String) -> Bool
nonBlank tuple =
  case tuple of
    (0, _) -> False
    (_, "") -> False
    _ -> True
```

This line declares `State`, which stores a function, which receives an argument and returns a tuple:

```
newtype State s a = StateOf{deState :: s -> (s, a)}
```

And this line defines `>>=` function for this type:

```
StateOf t >>= k = StateOf (\i0 -> case t i0 of
                              (i1, a) -> deState (k a) i1)
```

You probably confused by the `t i0`, but actually, when you understand, that the type of `t` is a function `s -> (s, a)`, then it's clear that `t i0` returns a tuple, which you can pattern match.